# ActiveRecord query with OR operators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I have `ActiveRecord` model class with scoped like below.

```
scope :acknowledgeable, -> { with_message.where(messages: { acknowledgeable: true }) }
scope :acknowledged, -> { acknowledgeable.where.not(acknowledged_at: nil) }
scope :not_acknowledged, -> { acknowledgeable.where(acknowledged_at: nil) }
scope :not_read, -> do
  message_statuses = MessageStatus.arel_table
  messages = Message.arel_table
  GuestMessageStatus.joins(:message).where(
    message_statuses[:read_at].eq(nil)
    .or(
      messages[:acknowledgeable].eq(true)
      .and(message_statuses[:read_at].eq(nil))
      .and(message_statuses[:acknowledged_at].eq(nil)))
 )
end
```

Scope `not_read` is object of my concern. Basically it works as it should. Can it be written in more elegant, easier way? I don't want to write it with raw SQL. The status message is considered as read when

```
if status.message.acknowledgeable?
  status.read_at.nil? && status.acknowledged_at.nil?
else
  status.read_at.nil?
end
```

Comment: `I don't want to write it with raw SQL`. Why? There is nothing wrong to write part of the `where` conditions with SQL strings. It's faster and you got a better visual idea of the result.

Comment: Simone Carletti you are right. I totally agree with your point of view. But I wonder if/how it could be rewritten without hardcoding SQL in it. I am not fluent in Arel and writting 'OR' queries always drives me to mental question - which approach is correct. SQL would be best for me if I need to use some SQL function like `DATE_FORMAT`.

Comment: You can check out this gem: https://github.com/oelmekki/activerecord_any_of

Comment: Or create an abstraction over ARel: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/using-arel-to-compose-sql-queries